# Linked against vs linked with

Tags: phrase-usage

I am reading a technical document but I believe this usage question is not limited to that.

The document talks about 2 components that need to be linked with each other, but instead in **linked with** it uses **linked against**:

> Applications that use the libraries provided must:
>
> • **Link against** any dependencies of the desired library.
>
> • **Link against** a version of the desired library

I was assuming that **linked with** is the right usage. Do you have ideas why **linked against** is preferred here? It doesn't sound natural.

Comment: **against** is correct in that technical context. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=compiled+against%2Clinked+against&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccompiled%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clinked%20against%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo What about this then:
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=linked+with%2Clinked+against&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clinked%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clinked%20against%3B%2Cc0

Comment: What I think about it is that you did not take the time to  look at the individual textual attestations that back my ngram, or at those that back yours.

Comment: I can't think of any case except the computer science one in which something is `linked against` another, so the usage question really is limited to just this case.  And yes, in computer science, one library is linked against another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a relevant Q/A on Stack Overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177550/what-does-it-mean-to-link-against-something

tldr; To link against something is to link only partially - or to several nodes of a thing, without bonding the two in totality.